# DB2 restore from encrypted back-up

Tags: db2, backup, restore, db2-luw, database-restore

I am trying to restore a DB2 database using an encrypted backup file. The backup zip file contains an .lst file, a .ddl file, over 3000 .ixf files, same number of message files and a folder with few .lob files in it.

I have tried using `bind @ list_file grant public` after placing the .lst file and .ixf files in the /bind directory. But the error was that .ixf files could not be opened.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather it is an administrative question. Do you have any Db2 skills?  Please edit your question to add context, for example: What is your Db2-server platform? What tools are you using? What is in the DDL file? Why do you believe it is an encrypted backup? Do you know about `db2move` command?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a backup (encrypted or otherwise) but the output from the `db2move export` command execution. Read the `db2move` documentation to learn how to perform the opposite operation.